# Is it possible to auto-rotate a modal view but not its parent?

Tags: iphone, autorotate

It seems that if a modal view's parent returns false to shouldAutoRotate... the modal view will also not autorotate. How can I have a main view which will never rotate, and a modal view which will always rotate?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to observe for orientation events (UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification) in your modal view controller and then add a transformation to your view layer using the CATransform3DMakeRotation to get an appropriate rotation around Z or basically with

```
[myLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:M_PI*0.5f] forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]; // or - M_PI*0.5f depending orientation: left or right
```

You can also use an animation to get an animated rotation. Is it what you're asking for?

For observing orientation events read this chapter :
[Getting the Current Device Orientation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH14-SW18)

For Layer transform read this chapter :
[Layer Geometry and Transforms](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082)

Regards.

V.Zgueb

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sure you can. Pretty much same advice like here I've [posted recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876682/stop-a-modal-uiviewcontroller-from-rotating?answertab=active#tab-top) just in different direction.

You need allow rotation on Modal, witch is by default. And disable it on Main controller.

This should work fine.