# Stop a modal UIViewController from rotating

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, autorotate

The modal `UIViewController`'s parent auto-rotates, but when the modal VC is up I only want it to appear in portrait and not be rotatable. I have tried simply returning NO from `shouldAutorotate`... in the modal VC, but no joy. Supporting iOS 5+.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, if you presenting Modal Controller on ***Any Container Controllers*** (i.e. UINavigationController) it have autorotation method return **YES** by default. So you have to make subclass for your UINavigation Controller and Deprecate Autorotation there.

For iOS 5 use method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) : self.enableRotations;
}
```

for iOS 6:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom) {

        case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad:   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone: return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Worked a charm.

Comment: Hi Andrey, what you mean by subclass for your container? do you mean there is need to use a subclass of the actual container ? mean move all the code from the actual controller to a subclass of it ? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

It can be doable, but I would think twice before doing that.

As a user;

- I launch the app and use in landscape.
- trigger an event (eg. press button).
- see a view which is portrait.
- rotate the phone and look in portrait.
- close the modal view.
- get landscape view again.
- need to rotate the phone again

Bad usability...

Answer (score 0):

you have to present that new controller on a new navigation controller.This will solve your problem