# iOS 6 controlling autorotation of view controllers behind UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

My iPad app has a `UIViewController` called `MainViewController` which presents a modal page sheet `UIViewController` called `ModalViewController`. `ModalViewController` then presents a `UIImagePickerController`.

Here is **MainViewController.m**:

```
@implementation MainViewController {

...

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

...

}
```

So it rotates to either of the landscape orientations, and when `ModalViewController` is presented it rotates that correctly also.

However when the `UIImagePickerController` is presented, it allows rotation to landscape or portrait orientations, and this allows `MainViewController` and `ModalViewController` to rotate to un-desired orientations.

How can I prevent `MainViewController` and `ModalViewController` from rotating when the `UIImagePickerController` is on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same problem asked here [Stop a modal UIViewController from rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876682/stop-a-modal-uiviewcontroller-from-rotating) ? If you're using a `UINavigationController` in the end you can subclass it and control the mechanism for rotation

Comment: No that's not the same problem. I've already subclass the container view controllers so that it delegates rotation to the top-most view controller. The problem is that I want the camera modal to rotate to any orientation but I need the controllers behind it not to rotate, or at least end up in the correction orientation when the camera modal is dismissed.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Then if you still want to allow the UIImagePicker controller to rotate but you don't want that for the underlying controllers, have you considered rotating the layer for these? You could check in the rotation callback if the orientation is one that you intend to support and if it's not the case, you can just rotate the layer so that in the end it's still "displayed" as you want it to.

Comment: Is this a "correct" way of doing things? I'm concerned that the status bar wouldn't necessarily be in the correct place, and `self.view.frame` wouldn't be as expected.